# How to redirect my settings page after successful login in tank auth

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to redirect my setting page after successful login in tank auth

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    // validation ok
    if ($this->tank_auth->login(
        $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
        $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
        $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
        $data['login_by_username'],
        $data['login_by_email'])) {

    // success
    redirect('/auth/user_profile');
```

But its not redirecting shows 404 error

Comment: try   redirect(base_url().'/auth/user_profile');

Comment: noo still 404 error only

Comment: is any id need LIKE redirect('/auth/user_profile/1231'); @vellaidurai

Comment: it is not redirecting to any page... i have just given after successful login just redirect to some page but its not redirecting

Comment: loaded libarary ? @vellaidurai   $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: auth controller doesnt contain function user_profile @vellaidurai

Comment: so i have to create a function user_profile in auth controller  to load the view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108920/discussion-between-maninderpreet-singh-and-vellai-durai).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your log files and post here. It may help us find the issue. Set log threshold to 4 in 'config/config.php' and check 'application/logs'. Also, make sure you are getting inside the second if condition. ie.

```
 if ($this->tank_auth->login() {
```

If it is getting inside it, check if there is any extra unwanted space (whitespace) or something in the related files.

Comment: INFO - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> Language Class Initialized
ERROR - 2016-04-12 10:40:08 --> 404 Page Not Found: Auth/user_profile

Comment: Can you please confirm, whether there is a method named user_profile in your Auth Class? after login you should be redirecting somewhere other than Auth, right?

Answer (score -2):

You have error with your code
try this

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {                             // validation ok
            if ($this->tank_auth->login(
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
                    $data['login_by_username'],
                    $data['login_by_email'])) }
                                                        // success
                redirect('/auth/user_profile');
```

You type  `$data['login_by_email'])) {`. But this is wrong. You should type  `$data['login_by_email'])) }`